# Mapping a JSON to Parent - Child Java Object

Tags: java, json, spring, annotations, jackson

Trying to map a JSON to a Java Class with the help of Spring.
I have a JSON Object which consists of flag as a key, and depending on its value of true or false, I need to fill the java classes which has a parent-child relationship amongst them.

```
class Parent {
   String name;
   String alias;
}

class Child extends Parent {
    ArrayList<Node> nodes;
}
```

If the value of flag is true then the JSON will contain nodes. So it should map the nodes to a variable declared in a child class.
if the value of flag is false then the JSON should fill the parent class.

Also I have tried the following solution given on many websites :-

```
@JsonSerialize(include=JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT, property = "flag")
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value=Child.class, name="true"),
})
```

But while returning a JSON from my Rest Service it returns the name of the class in JSON.

Comment: Can you please provide the solution overlooking whatever i have tried ???

Comment: It should be possible to parse the JSON string to retrieve the flag and then parse the rest of the JSON however you need to, but you will need to provide a sample JSON string and/or the parsing code you have currently in order for people to help you out most effectively.